# How to assign some matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot side by side in another pyplot.subplots array

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, subplot

I have a function that returns a matplotlib.axes._subplots object, and I would like put some of these outputs side by side in another subplots, but I get the plots of these objects separately, and one empty plot for the new subplot. What I am looking for is just a plot including 4 plots. *I know how to plot side by side* by adding items one by one to subplots, but I would like to see if I can assign an axes object to another like following codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def plot_sub(x , y, title):
    fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_title(title)
    return ax 
x=range(0,10)
y=[np.random.uniform(0,1,10) for i in range(4)]
fig1, ax1=plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        ax1[i,j]=plot_sub(x,y[j+2*i], f'{i},{j}')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Strongly recommend that you refactor this so that your plotting method accepts the axes as an argument.  Then create the figure and axes outside your method.  You cannot really move an axes from one figure to another.

Comment: @JodyKlymak , Thank you, I knew that way and tried it, it works but I don't understand why this way does not work

Comment: Because an axes has a figure as a parent, and can't be adopted by a different parent.  Its just a one way street.  I guess theoretically that is not required (you could think of any Artist as a standalone thing) but in practice matplotlib doesn't allow moving Artists around.